# Python mutate existing dict analogous to slice assignment for lists?

Tags: python, dictionary

This seemed like a really simple question, but google searches didn't show me much because I am not sure of the right terminology to use here.

Consider the following snippet for list

```
l1 = [5]

def change_global():
    l1[:] = [1, 2, 3, 4]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    change_global()
    print(l1) # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I have successfully managed to assign to and mutate a global list using the slice notation.

I want something similar for a dictionary. `update` doesn't work because I want to discard any existing items in the global dictionary. I know I can do:

```
global_dict.clear()
global_dict.update(new_dict)
```

But is there a one liner analogous to the list example ?

**EDIT:**

After looking at a comment I tried the following

```
d1 = {}

def change_global():
    d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

This does not change d1 unless I use the global keyword, and yet the slice notation works for the list example. So it definitely means that the slice notation is somehow special here.

Comment: The slice notation is *special* because it calls the list's `__setitem__` method as opposed to `d = ...` which is just an assignment to a new *local* variable (a correction to my previous deleted comment)

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @VikashB no, it does not work fine for the list. In any case, you already have a solution. What is the problem with your solution? Why is 2 lines too many? If you are writing it many times, put it in a function and call the function. Or here, two simple statements on one line: `d.clear(); d.update(new_dict)`. But that is against the style guide... just use two lines.

Comment: Do you want to only have one dict object, do you want to set a global variable to a new dict object each time, or does it not matter? (Situations where the value is held onto without copying, like `local_d = d1; change_global(); local_d == d1  # ?`.)

Comment: "This does not change d1 unless I use the global keyword, and yet it works for the list example." - no, it would need a `global` declaration with a list too.

Comment: I don't recommend this over the two line solutions (or using globals at all), but a one-liner would be `globals()['d'] = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}`. This is of course just a rebinding and fundamentally different to the mutation of the slice assignment.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga There doesn't have to be any problem with my solution. I know two lines is not too much. I was just curious if there was an analogue and I think my question definitely phrased it that way as well?

Comment: @VikashB there isn't. `.update` is the closest. `dict` objects don't support slices with item-assignment

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I meant the slice notation, edited to reflect that.

Comment: @VikashB the key thing to understand is that item-assignment, i.e. `x[something] = another` is not the same as assignment, it is essentially sugar for `x.__setitem__(something, another)`, for built-in types, it is a mutator method. Although you can define the behavior however you want in a custom class. Normal assignment never mutates. And you can't define custom assignment semantics.